# Why directive inside ui-view of parent template execute again when going to child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

Whenever the child state is invoked, the directive inside parent state is loaded again (second time). Is it possible to prevent the loading of directive when the child state is invoked?

Use Case:

```
module.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
            url: 'parent',
            templateUrl: 'parent.html',
            controller: "ParentController"
        })
   .state('parent.child',{
            url:'/child',
            templateUrl: 'child.html',
            controller: "ChildController"
        })
});

module.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function() {
            console.log('directive is called');
        }
    }
})

//parent.html
<div ui-view>
    <my-directive></my-directive>     
</div>

<button type="button" ui-sref="parent.child">Switch</button>
```

When you click on the button, **myDirective** executes again and **ui-view** div is replaced with **child.html**.

Comment: try this :-
//parent.html
  <my-directive></my-directive>     
<div ui-view>
  
</div>
You can't prevent loading of directive again reason is very simple . You are using this inside ui-view. When your child page is going to load at that time your  ui-view is refreshed ,hence it is again call your directive.